# Craft CMS development licensing issues

Tags: craft3, license, windows

I have a Craft CMS installed in a development environment thewebsite.test.

I can't get it to trial paid plugins and Craft Pro.

It appears Craft doesn't recognise it's in a development environment?

**Application Info**

- PHP version  7.4.2
- OS version   Linux 4.15.0-74-ubuntu
- Database driver & version    MySQL 5.5.5
- Craft edition & version  Craft Pro 3.4.6.1

I'm running Windows 10 with Vagrant/Homestead with Craft installed on a Virtual Machine in VirtualBox.

The same setup on a Mac does not have any issues with licensing.

I have copied the database and updated the .env file from the Mac install, and everything appears to be working except for the licensing issues.

Is there any way to force Craft CMS to recognise a dev environment?

Comment: Are you able to load the "updates" page in the Craft control panel without any errors or issues?

Comment: Yes, can load the "updates" page in the control panel. No errors. Two updates available 3.4.7 and 3.4.7.1

Comment: Well, now I'm confused. Can you shoot your `config/license.key` file over to support@craftcms.com and reference this SE post?

Comment: I never solved this. I instead switched to running Craft in DDEV instead and didn't have the issue. I suspect it may have been something in the vagrant stack combined with using GitBash WSL and the Untuntu VM. Somethings may have been run or installed in the wrong terminal/environment?

Answer (score 1):

did you copy the `license.key` from your Mac environment to the Windows/Vagrant environment? Maybe deleting the `license.key` would help in this case.

Comment: Hi Denis,  
Yes copied the `license.key` and tried deleting `license.key` and Craft still doesn't appear to recognise it's in a development environment.  

Also deleted `/vendor` and `/storage/*` folders and did a `composer install` and still no luck.

Comment: Experiencing something similar... Developed my project without issues, but once I moved to production and bought the license, all of a sudden dev environment started to bother about license... I'm puzzled.